# How to send multiple Http request using single Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I am trying to create an angular app which can send multiple HTTP requests, based on the options selected by a user from a [drop-down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVZZR.jpg), using observables. I checked online but wasn't able to understand the concepts fully. I am not able to use `switchMap operator` in order to achieve my goals.

Can anyone please have a look and point out my error.

Any suggestions/help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

.component.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

// Router Module for Application level Route
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

//importing route code
import { CountryLanguageService } from '../country-language.service';
import { CountryLanguageHttpService } from '../country-language-http.service';


//importing observables related code
import { Observable, pipe } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-language',
  templateUrl: './language.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./language.component.css']
})
export class LanguageComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  public allSameLanguagesCountries;
  public selectedCode;

  constructor(private countryLanguageHttpService: CountryLanguageHttpService, private _route: ActivatedRoute, private location: Location) {

    console.log("Languages Component Called");
  }

  backClicked() {
    this.location.back();
  }


  ngOnInit() {

    // method to get all same language speaking countries

    this._route.params
    .pipe(switchMap(params => this.selectedCode = params['code']));
    console.log(this.selectedCode);
    this.allSameLanguagesCountries = this.countryLanguageHttpService.getAllSameLanguagesCountries(this.selectedCode)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log(data);
          this.allSameLanguagesCountries = data;

        },
        error => {
          console.log("Some Error Occurred");
          console.log(error.errorMessage);
        }
      )
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    console.log("Language Component Destroyed");
  }
}
```

.http-service.ts file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

//importing Http Client to make the request
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

// Router Module for Application level Route
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

//importing observables related code
import { Observable, pipe } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})


export class CountryLanguageHttpService {

  public currentLanguageCode;

  public baseUrl = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/lang/';

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { 
    console.log("Country Language View Service Called");

  }

  // Exception Handler
  private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    console.log("Handle error Http calls")
    console.log(err.message);
    return Observable.throw(err.message);
  }


  // method to return single country Informations
  public getAllSameLanguagesCountries(currentLanguageCode): any {

    let myResponse = this._http.get(this.baseUrl + currentLanguageCode);
    console.log(myResponse);
    return myResponse;
  } // end get country info function
}
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssGU3.jpg) is the error I am getting in console.

Comment: I could see a 404 error while calling `v2/lang/undefined`. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: Ankit: Yes, also, I am not able to understand how to make the request using switchMap operator.

Comment: `switchMap` should return an `Observable`, otherwise use `map`

Comment: Then the error results because your web endpoint could not be found. Whereas, if we talk about `rxjs`'s `switchMap` operator, then it is not making any call to the back end. It simply switches to a new observable and maps the response in the desired format. Moreover, it has a cancelling effect on the API. That is if same end point is hit twice and the latter brings the response first and the former later on, then you will be working with the response from the former web call that was made. Using swicthMap cancels any previous observable.

Comment: So you are always working with the latest web call that was made. Refer https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html for more information about `switchMap`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

switchMap change an observable to another. See

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._route.params
      .pipe(switchMap(params => 
        {
           //We don't want return the params
           this.selectedCode = params['code']);
           //we want return the countries
           return this.countryLanguageHttpService.getAllSameLanguagesCountries(this.selectedCode)
        }))
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log(data);
          this.allSameLanguagesCountries = data;
        },
        error => {
          console.log("Some Error Occurred");
          console.log(error.errorMessage);
        })
  }
```